# Mathematica enumerate combinations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, combinations

I need to enumerate combinations for 3 groups of values that I have. The groups are (a,b,c,d), (e,f,g,h), (i,j,k,l) for example. The total combinations are 4x4x4=64. 
Has anyone an idea, how can I define the ascending numbering of these combinations? 
I have written something in that form:

```
Do[Do[Do[x["formula is needed here"]=s[[i,j,k]],{k,1,4}],{j,1,4}],{i,1,4}]
```

I cannot find the formula for the numbering of the combinations. I have read something about "Generating the mth Lexicographical Element of a Mathematical Combination" but I am more lost than helped. x is supposed to take values 1,2,3,....,64. 
Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need a "formula" for the 'nth' tuple it looks like this:

```
{ Floor[(# - 1)/16      ] + 1,
  Floor[Mod[# - 1, 16]/4] + 1 , 
  Floor[Mod[# - 1, 4]   ] + 1 } & /@ Range[64] ==
  Tuples[Range[4], 3]
```

> True

so then if you want say the 12'th combination of your sets you could do something like this:

```
({ 
     Floor[(# - 1)/16] + 1,
     Floor[Mod[# - 1, 16]/4 + 1] ,
     Mod[# - 1, 4] + 1 } &@12);
{{a, b, c, d}[[%[[1]]]], {e, f, g, h}[[%[[2]]]], {i, j, k, 
   l}[[%[[3]]]]}
```

> {a, g, l}

note that whatever you are doing it is almost always best to use the built in object oriented functions.

```
 Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}}][[12]]
```

> {a, g, l}

Edit: for completeness a generalization of the first expression:

```
listlen = 6;
nsamp = 4;
Table[Floor[Mod[# - 1, listlen^i]/listlen^(i - 1) + 1], {i, nsamp, 
     1, -1}] & /@ Range[listlen^nsamp] ==
  Tuples[Range[listlen], nsamp]
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}}]
```